# Custom collection of variables (similar to Array) in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I had always thought that Arrays in C# are no different from other collections. It's just a mutable and fixed-size collection. But upon looking at it in more detail, it seems that Arrays are quite fundamentally different because it's a collection of *variables*, not *values*:

```
var array = new MyStruct[] { new MyStruct() };
var list = new List<MyStruct> { new MyStruct() };

array[0].Value = 1; // Legal
list[0].Value = 2; // Illegal

var listElement = list[0];
listElement.Value = 3; // This is legal, but is different from mutating array[0] because accessing list[0] makes a copy

struct MyStruct // Yes, an evil mutable struct
{
    public int Value;
}
```

My questions:

1. Is there any way to write a custom collection in C# that mimics the array behavior, i.e. is a collection of variables instead of values?
2. If not, does this mean that arrays are magical in this sense and fundamentally different from all other collections?

Comment: Make a collection that overloads the indexer to return by `ref` instead of by value?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, arrays *are* collections of variables. From the [C# 7 standard](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v7/standard/arrays.md): "An array is a data structure that contains a number of variables that are accessed through computed indices." Likewise, that's one reason [array access](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v7/standard/expressions.md#128112-array-access) is separate from [indexer access](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v7/standard/expressions.md#128113-indexer-access).

Comment: @UnholySheep That makes a lot of sense - I guess arrays can be thought as collections that return by reference in it's indexer. One implication of that is there's no way to mimic the array behavior pre-C# 7, I suppose.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon for pointing to the relevant parts in the specs. It all makes sense now after realizing that arrays effectively provide `ref` access to its contents. BTW do you have an RSS feed monitoring C# questions on SO because that is real quick response! :)

Comment: Nope, I just check SO fairly frequently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are indeed special in C#; they provide direct memory access, which allows modification of struct elements in-place. Most other collections copy the struct when you access an element.

##### Custom Collection Mimicking Array Behavior

You can mimic this behavior using `ref` returns:

```cs
public class MyArray<T> where T : struct
{
    private T[] _data;

    public MyArray(int length)
    {
        _data = new T[length];
    }

    public ref T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= _data.Length) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            return ref _data[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var myArray = new MyArray<MyStruct>(1);
myArray[0].Value = 1;  // Legal
```

##### Arrays Are Special

Yes, arrays are fundamentally different because they're directly supported by the CLR and provide a way to interact with memory in a more direct fashion.

So, while you can mimic array behavior, the built-in arrays have special optimizations and runtime support that custom collections won't have.

Comment: Why do you claim you need `unsafe` and pointers? This code would work just as well with a normal managed array

Comment: You're correct; my mistake. You can achieve similar behavior without unsafe code by using a managed array internally. The key is to use ref returns.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Never realized that ref returns had effectively existed in C# since the beginning in the form of array indexers.